# Excel function, exclude dates in chart data source, excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am forming a chart from sheet A. Sheet B contains all my data.
I want to exclude a specified date(s).

Sample data:

```
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |    A     |      B       |      C       |      D      |      E      |      F      |
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Date     | 29/03/2017   | 30/03/2017   | 31/03/2017  | 03/04/2017  | 04/04/2017  |
| 2 | Number 1 | -594590.4649 | -636666.4504 | 795637.1614 | 842563.4322 | 496463.9301 |
| 3 | Number 2 | 2189587.44   | 1301681.418  | 2080839.353 | 1945335.214 | 2421728.123 |
+---+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The final output would be me excluding 30/03/2017 , and keeping the rest in my data selected for my chart.
the issue is that I want to maybe exclude a date in the middle of my selected range. But since this may be a hassle to input a long formula each time into my data selected. I would like to see if there is any formula/function to eliminate a specified date/column. Perhaps manually enter the column you want to exclude in a formula.

My current range is something like `=Graph!$AB$5:$KA$7`  But is there a function to exclude one of these columns?

I can manually select which dates with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but seems tedious.

I originally posted this in stackoverflow but may be better for super user.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, this is easy. Make the chart with all of the data. Select the chart, and click on the lowest of the three "skittles" floating beside the chart. Uncheck the box next to the unwanted date in the flyout, and click Apply.

[image: Filter Dates In Chart]

If you don't have 2013+ you can hide the columns with unwanted dates. By default, Excel doesn't show data in the chart if the rows or columns are hidden.

But it's easier to do if you arrange your data in columns instead of rows, and put it into a Table. Select the data in columns, press Ctrl+T, and check the appropriate box (whether you have headers).

Here's a Table and an unfiltered chart.

[image: Unfiltered Dates in Table]

Now you can use the Table's flexible filtering tools. Below, I'm simply deselecting the unwanted date, but you can also set up filters like Between, Before, After, etc.

[image: Excel's Table Filters]

And here's my filtered Table and chart. Note the blue row headers on the left which indicate the table is now filtered, and the double line between rows 3 and 5 showing where the row(s) were hidden.

[image]

Comment: thanks Jon.. I did come across this, but if I do not have excel 2013 , was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: You can hide the columns for the dates you don't want. By default, Excel doesn't show data in the chart if the rows or columns are hidden.

Comment: It's easier to set up the data in columns instead of rows. Then the data can be in a table, and you can use the filtering tools to hide and show rows based on whatever criteria you can think of. I've added this to my answer.